# UserAppDataReigistry not persisting

Tags: c#, devexpress, registry

I have the following class to persist my camera settings.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Camera;        

public class CameraDeviceHelper
    {
        public string DeviceMoniker;
        public string DeviceName;
        public int DeviceResolutionWidth;
        public int DeviceResolutionHeight;

        const string kDeviceName = "CameraDeviceName";
        const string kDeviceMoniker = "CameraDeviceMoniker";
        const string kDeviceResolutionWidth = "CameraDeviceResolutionWidth";
        const string kDeviceResolutionHeight = "CameraDeviceResolutionHeight";

        public bool SaveCameraDevice(CameraControl cc)
        {
            try
            {
                DeviceMoniker = cc.Device.DeviceMoniker;
                DeviceName = cc.Device.Name;
                DeviceResolutionWidth = cc.Device.Resolution.Width;
                DeviceResolutionHeight = cc.Device.Resolution.Height;

                Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue(kDeviceName, DeviceName);
                Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue(kDeviceMoniker, DeviceMoniker);
                Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue(kDeviceResolutionWidth, DeviceResolutionWidth);
                Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue(kDeviceResolutionHeight, DeviceResolutionHeight);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;

            }

        }
        public bool RestoreCameraDevice(CameraControl cc)
        {
            try
            {
                DeviceName = Application.UserAppDataRegistry.GetValue(kDeviceName, DeviceName).ToString();
                DeviceMoniker =Application.UserAppDataRegistry.GetValue(kDeviceMoniker, DeviceMoniker).ToString();
                DeviceResolutionWidth = (int) Application.UserAppDataRegistry.GetValue(kDeviceResolutionWidth, DeviceResolutionWidth);
                DeviceResolutionHeight = (int)Application.UserAppDataRegistry.GetValue(kDeviceResolutionHeight, DeviceResolutionHeight);

                var moniker = new DevExpress.Data.Camera.CameraDeviceInfo(DeviceMoniker, DeviceName);
                cc.Device = new CameraDevice(moniker);
                var sz = new Size(DeviceResolutionWidth,DeviceResolutionHeight);
                cc.Device.Resolution = sz;
                if (cc.Device.Resolution.Width != sz.Width)
                { MessageBox.Show("Not set");}

                cc.Start();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

The persisting works while the application runs.
However when I restart the application the settings are lost.

I call the methods in my form's load and FormClosed events

```
    private void Camera_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textEdit1.Text = PhotoCaption;
        cameraDeviceHelper = new CameraDeviceHelper();
        try
        {
            cameraDeviceHelper.RestoreCameraDevice(cameraControl1);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // probably first time... so just dont complain
            throw;
        }

    }

    private void Camera_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        cameraDeviceHelper.SaveCameraDevice(cameraControl1);
    }
```

Comment: Show all relevant code.  E.g. ALL places you're calling `SaveCameraDevice` and `RestoreCameraDevice`.

Comment: do you serialise then back to the file? see this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms973902.aspx

Comment: Looking at http://geekswithblogs.net/whiletrue/archive/2009/01/11/save-configuration-settings-in-registry.aspx

Comment: I can get it to work by removing the * in AssemblyVersion in AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: @MatthewFlynn  I am saving to the registry so no need to involve a file

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to have an * in the AssemblyVersion
otherwise every time the application is built the registry key will change.