# How can I freeze the video displayed in the CameraControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How can I freeze the video displayed in the CameraControl when TakeSnapshot() has been called in order to display the fetched image?

Basically, I would like to rebuild the same capture behaviour as in the devexpress TakePictureDialog class in my own form, because in the TakePictureDialog it does not seem to be possible to store the user-selected camera device, which I need to do in my app, though.

I followed the instructions and examples in these articles:

- https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T269133/obtaining-the-last-selected-camera-device-and-restoring-it-in-a-takepicturedialog
- https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114582/Controls-and-Libraries/Editors-and-Simple-Controls/Camera-Control
- [UserAppDataReigistry not persisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756111/userappdatareigistry-not-persisting)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the stackoverflow.

CameraControl doesn't provide that functionality itself.

Either way you can use the Paint event to render the image, obtained via TakeSnapshot.

Something like this:

```
private void CameraControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    CameraControl c = sender as CameraControl;
    if (isStopped && img != null)
         e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0,0, c.Width, c.Height));
}


bool isStopped = false;
Bitmap img;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    img = cameraControl1.TakeSnapshot();
    cameraControl1.Stop();
    isStopped = true;
}
```

Credits from devexpress.com